# how to record audio and video while video call streaming using in WebRTC natively?

Tags: android, webrtc

I am working on recording video in Android device (locally) while streaming video call using WebRTC. I search lots of I cant get any idea. I'm following this article   [WebRTCArticle](https://vivekc.xyz/getting-started-with-webrtc-for-android-daab1e268ff4)

Please help and suggest how can record video in locally in android only

Comment: Any solution???

Comment: Not yet. tell me if you find some good articles or solution on this problem